# the following code should turn on the camera and record video on my android phone. However, nothing happens. Anybody spot any errors in my code?

Tags: java, android, camera, recording

I have used this code to create (trying) an app that opens its camera and starts recording videos, whether front or back, doesn't matter. But what ever i have tried i cannot seem to get it to work. When i press the button, nothing happens, no crash, no new view. I am not sure what the problem is.

```
package com.example.mediaworld;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;
public MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();
private Button startRecording = null;
//private button stopRecording;
File video;
private Camera mCamera;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.i(null, "Video starting");
    startRecording = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    menu.add(0,0,0, "StartRecording");
    menu.add(0,1,0, "StopRecording");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    //int id = item.getItemId();
    //if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    //  return true;
    //}

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case 0: try{
        startRecording();
    }catch(Exception e){
        String message = e.getMessage();
        Log.i(null, "problem Start" + message);
        mrec.release();
    }
    break; 

    case 1:
        mrec.stop();
        mrec.release();
        mrec = null;
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void startRecording() throws IOException{
    mrec = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.unlock();

    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);

    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

    mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    mrec.setOutputFile("/sdcard/zzzz/3gp");


    mrec.prepare();
    mrec.start();
}

protected void stopRecording(){
    mrec.stop();
    mrec.release();
    mCamera.release();
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if(mrec != null){
        mrec.reset();
        mrec.release();
        mrec = null;
        mCamera.lock();
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if(mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}



@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(mCamera != null){
        Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}
}
```

And here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mediaworld"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name= "android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

AND here is the xml file for main activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.mediaworld.MainActivity" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonstart"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="Start Rec" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to register an "onClickListener" with your button:

```
startRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startRecording();
    }
});
```

Comment: You said, that "nothing happens", once you press the button. Now you say it "just crashes".... does this mean that your first problem ("nothing happens when the button is being pressed") has been solved?